# TIME Columns as primary key

Tags: mysql, primary-key

From a long time ago, and because several reasons, I have understood that no `DATETIME` columns should not form part of the primary key of a table. Between these reasons, I think it is a bad idea given the high precision of this field. An example, `2014-06-26 15:35:12` won't match  `2014-06-26 15:35:13`.

Questions like [Use timestamp(or datetime) as part of primary key (or part of clustered index)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851129/use-timestampor-datetime-as-part-of-primary-key-or-part-of-clustered-index) seem to support this "phobia".

However I am facing now a very concrete problem: I want to map into a MySQL table some values of a function like

```
f:(TimeInDay,TimeInDay) -> Integer
```

Where the arguments represent a time interval (with second precision) within the same day.
Unique `(TimeInDay,TimeInDay)` pairs results in a concrete output value. So I came to this table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE sessions_schedule
(
    tIni TIME NOT NULL,
    tEnd TIME NOT NULL,
    X  tinyInt,
    CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (tIni, tEnd)
);
```

Where `TIME`s compose the primary key.

In the [MySQL online manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/time.html) I found:

> MySQL recognizes TIME values in several formats,... Some of these
>   formats can include a trailing fractional seconds part in up to
>   microseconds (6 digits) precision. Although this fractional part is
>   recognized, it is discarded from values stored into TIME columns.

So, it seems to me, that in this case the inclusion of `TIME` fields in the primary key is justified. Am I right?

Comment: So you want such PK because of performance or did I miss something?

Comment: i would convert the two times to an int and store that. If its to seconds and in one day would be from 0 to 60*60*24 only, so even if input to your is date-time of a day, you convert to int and use.

Comment: @tgkprog Yes, I thought something like that but I wonder why, in this case, should we run from using `TIME`. Is it justified?

Comment: @N.B. Between other advantages such as being able to make inserts like this one: `INSERT INTO sessions_schedule VALUES ('173000', '183000', 3)`.

Comment: It seems far fetched that you would have colliding time in and out, but you could always make the primary key have an additional field for id just to be sure.  I could see something like Facebook possibly having collisions, since they have so many users.

Comment: You are quite right that the key should include the time(s). Give some thought to how you create the constraint if overlapping intervals are disallowed. Also consider using half-open intervals for your time periods. If you use a half-open model for time intervals and you don't want to allow overlapping intervals then the table would be keyed on the start point (and maybe the end point as well) rather than a composite of both start and end point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> From a long time ago, and because several reasons, I have understood
>   that no DATETIME columns should not form part of the primary key of a
>   table.

That's not true for the relational model, it's not true of SQL in general, and it's not true of MySQL in particular.

> Between these reasons, I think it is a bad idea given the high
>   precision of this field. An example, 2014-06-26 15:35:12 won't match
>   2014-06-26 15:35:13.

Your example isn't a good one. Think about using integers instead. Would you expect the integer 3 to match the integer 4? Of course not. So why would you think '2014-06-26 15:35:12' would match '2014-06-26 15:35:13'? They're *different values*. Different values *aren't supposed to match*.

> So, it seems to me, that in this case the inclusion of TIME fields in
>   the primary key is justified. Am I right?

Quite likely. You just have to make sure that you

- don't store any values more precise than a second, and
- tIni is before tEnd.

([MySQL *can* store trailing microseconds](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fractional-seconds.html).)

On other platforms, you'd probably use CHECK constraints to enforce those requirements, but MySQL doesn't enforce CHECK constraints. You'll need to write triggers, or revoke permissions on the tables, and require changes to go through a stored procedure.

Comment: Great answer, almost a pity to accept your answer and destroy your pseudo-palindromic reputation number! Just comment, TIME fields should not contain microseconds if not field length is provided, isn't it?

Comment: In standard SQL, `timestamp` is equivalent to `timestamp(6)`. In MySQL, `datetime` is equivalent to `datetime(0)`. Although you're right, you'll have to find your own comfort level with accepting the default behavior. We older database guys have seen defaults change over time. As a rule, defaults move closer to standards. The defensive programmer would write your CREATE TABLE statements using `datetime(0)`.