# Foreign Key with TimeStamp Incorrectly Formed

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm having some issues using MariaDB in XAMPP for OS X.

I'm developing a DataBase where I have to insert some foreign keys referenced to TIMESTAMP attributes in other tables.

When the system tries to process the "create foreign key" statement it gives me this error:

"errno: 150 "Foreign Key is incorrectly Formed"

Here are my SQL commands

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS cinguettio;
USE cinguettio;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS utente(
    email VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    città VARCHAR(30),
    stato VARCHAR(30),
    provincia VARCHAR(30),
    datanascita DATE,
    luogonascita VARCHAR(30),
    nome VARCHAR(30),
    cognome VARCHAR(30),
    vip VARCHAR(1),
    sesso VARCHAR(1),
    password VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS apprezzamento(
    dataora TIMESTAMP,
    email VARCHAR(50),
    testo VARCHAR(50),
    dataoraimm TIMESTAMP,
    id INT(7),
    PRIMARY KEY (dataora, email),
    FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES utente(email)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hobby(
    nome VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS immagine(
    id INT(7),
    dataora TIMESTAMP,
    email VARCHAR(50),
    nomefile VARCHAR(30),
    percorso VARCHAR(200),
    PRIMARY KEY (id, dataora, email),
    FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES utente(email)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS luogo(
    id INT(7),
    dataora TIMESTAMP,
    email VARCHAR(50),
    latitudine FLOAT(2,2), 
    longitudine FLOAT(2,2),
    PRIMARY KEY (id, dataora, email),
    FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES utente(email)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pratica(
    nome VARCHAR(20),
    email VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (nome, email),
    FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES utente(email),
    FOREIGN KEY (nome) REFERENCES hobby(nome)
);



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scrivea(
    dataora TIMESTAMP,
    email VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (dataora, email),
    FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES utente(email),
    FOREIGN KEY (dataora) REFERENCES apprezzamento(dataora)

);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testo(
    id INT(7),
    dataora TIMESTAMP,
    email VARCHAR(50),
    contenuto VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (id, dataora, email),
    FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES utente(email)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS segue(
    segue VARCHAR(50),
    seguito VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (segue, seguito),
    FOREIGN KEY (segue) REFERENCES utente(email),
    FOREIGN KEY (seguito) REFERENCES utente(email)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scrivet(
    id INT(7),
    dataora TIMESTAMP,
    email VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (id, dataora, email),
    FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES utente(email),

    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES testo(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS segnala(
    id INT(7),
    dataora TIMESTAMP,
    email VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (id, dataora, email),
    FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES utente(email),
    FOREIGN KEY (dataora) REFERENCES testo(dataora),
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES testo(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS preferisce(
    id INT(7),
    dataora TIMESTAMP,
    email VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (id, dataora, email),
    FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES utente(email),
    FOREIGN KEY (dataora) REFERENCES luogo(dataora),
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES luogo(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pubblica(
    id INT(7),
    dataora TIMESTAMP,
    email VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (id, dataora, email),
    FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES utente(email),
    FOREIGN KEY (dataora) REFERENCES luogo(dataora),
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES luogo(id)
);
```

Until the table "scrivet" everything goes fine, then it stops. I'm sure the problem is with the attribute "dataora" because I tried to delete it and it worked fine.

So...what should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use timestamp(or datetime) as part of primary key (or part of clustered index)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851129/use-timestampor-datetime-as-part-of-primary-key-or-part-of-clustered-index)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use timestamp in a composite key, or any key.

[Use timestamp(or datetime) as part of primary key (or part of clustered index)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851129/use-timestampor-datetime-as-part-of-primary-key-or-part-of-clustered-index)